# PHP question regarding a while statement for a loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I asked someone to code up a loop for me, although I asked for the loop to run constantly as it should be doing checks. Say I wanted it to run for 2 hours in a loop.

They created this;

```
$result = select_query ('tbltest', 'id,userid,test');

while ($data = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
    $userid = $data['userid'];
    $id = $data['id'];
    $test = $data['test'];
}
```

I don't know much about PHP, but it seems to me that once there are no more rows to go through and place in an array, it will end the loop.

How can I go about fetching the rows, but continuing in a loop for the next 2 hours?
Thanks!

Comment: The real question is why you want to do that? Once the result set have been read, there's no point resetting the cursor to read it again during 2 hours... What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you want to continue looping for 2 hours and doing nothing, but here's a solution (albeit a stupid one, if it serves your purpose):

```
set_time_limit(0);
$time = time();
while (time()<$time+7200)
{
    if ($data = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $userid = $data['userid'];
        $id = $data['id'];
        $test = $data['test'];
    }
    sleep(1); // so PHP doesn't consume too much resources
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand why OP wants to do that... anyway. Still, you should put a `usleep` call in your `while` if you don't want the CPU peaking at 100% for 2 hours.

Comment: did that while you were writing your comment

Comment: @stillstanding thank you. the script does a lot more, and requires a loop to continuously checking a value in a table. I implemented your script on 60 seconds as a test and it just won't run the loop :(

Comment: how sure are you that it doesn't? what do your error logs show?

Comment: @stillstanding i have it outputting to xml - was working before, now it isn't.

Comment: your problem has to be elsewhere. the code above works as specified. try removing the `if ($data...) { }` block. just leave the `sleep()` function inside the loop. see if it runs properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check something for a set amount of time, you should setup a cronjob to run a PHP script every X minutes rather than have a PHP script looping continuously.

Comment: I have a cron setup to begin the script, but the loop needs to run quicker than 1 minute intervals. Thanks simshaun

Answer (score 0):

you can't. when you do the select_query it actually returns a pointer of the full resultset as of that moment. the `$data = mysql_fetch_array ($result)` can only iterate over that values that were present in the resultset at the time of the initial `select_query ('tbltest', 'id,userid,test');`
 call.. not to mention that I can't think of any properly configured PHP server that's going to let you leave a script running for 2 hours without timing out. perhaps what you want is a front-page with a AJAX script that re-checks the database for you in a loop. so that you would have your $.GET, and on the successfull return of your data you'd fire off another $.GET...

Comment: can I change the $data = mysql_fetch_array ($result) to something else to run on loop for a check on a value, even for a few minutes? Just want to see if something is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put the original database query inside [stillstanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4248696/php-question-regarding-a-while-statement-for-a-loop/4248747#4248747)'s loop?

```
set_time_limit(0);
$time = time();
while (time()<$time+7200)
{
    $result = select_query ('tbltest', 'id,userid,test');

    if ($data = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
    {
        $userid = $data['userid'];
        $id = $data['id'];
        $test = $data['test'];
    }
    sleep(1); // so PHP doesn't consume too much resources
}
```